# MySQL subselect needed

Tags: mysql

I just can't figure this out.  I need a select statement that will find all job_id's where its profile_sent column is ALL non-zero.  So in this case the select should return just "2064056592" because all its rows for profile_sent are non-zero, but 4064056590 still has a 0 in one of its rows so it is not found.

I can obviously get the distinct job_id with:

```
mysql> Select distinct job_id from Table;
+------------+
| job_id     |
+------------+
| 4064056590 |
| 2064056592 |
+------------+
```

But have no idea how to subselect where each job_id has all its profile_sent column as non-zeros.

See https://snipboard.io/x4UNKc.jpg for the table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a subquery to find all the distinct `job_id`s with `profile_sent` as 0
and filtering them out should work:

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT t.`job_id` 
FROM
  test_table t 
WHERE t.`job_id` NOT IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.job_id 
  FROM
    test_table t1 
  WHERE t1.`profile_sent` = 0)
```

Another approach could be grouping them by their `job_id` and then checking the sum of `profile_sent` value is 0;

```
SELECT t.`job_id` FROM `test_table` t 
GROUP BY t.`job_id`
HAVING SUM(t.`profile_sent` = 0)=0
```